# List elements as comma seperated string - split and add to list using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have a `List<String>` where an element could have a comma seperated String.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2,3,4,5");
list.add("6,7");
list.add("8");
```

I would like to iterate through the list and split the comma seperated stuff into a new element by using Java 8 Streams. Means that every number should be an element in the list.

I was trying to use `.map()` and `.collect()`.

```
list.stream().map(l -> l.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But `split` returns a `String[]` which is not what I need.

Is there a way to get this done by using Java 8 Streams?

Comment: try this :    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
   list.stream().forEach(a -> {Arrays.asList( a.split(",")).stream().forEach(t-> {list2.add(t);});});  Create a new list to store elements. Then user stream and split each element in arry and add to the list 2

Comment: Do you want a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>` at the end?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch a List of String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list
    .stream()
    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We basically use `flatMap()` which has the effect of applying a one-to-many transformation to the elements of the stream, and then flattening the resulting elements into a new stream.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation.

Comment: perfect. `Arrays.stream(s.split(",")` is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the already provided working answer from @Tom I propose the following which makes use of the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class and its method `splitAsStream(String)` which was freshly introduced in `Java 8`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
List<String> split = list
    .stream()
    .flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```